# How i want to put limit on age, weight and height on my store procedure? i want it to have an output that have limit answer

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

i want it to have an output that have limit answer such as age 20 between 75, weight 50 between 120, height between 170?

should i create another variable or how?

here is my code :

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_asif_bmi (
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    age int NOT NULL,
    weight decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
    height decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
    bmi decimal(5,2)
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE load_bmi()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE counter int;
        DECLARE intAge int;
        SET counter = 1;
        START transaction;
    WHILE counter <= 200 DO
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_asif_bmi (name, weight, height)
        VALUES 
       (concat('User - ',counter), 
       CAST(RAND()*1 as DECIMAL(5,2)),
       CAST(RAND()*1 as DECIMAL(5,2)));
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END;
    END WHILE;
    WHILE intAge BETWEEN 20 AND 75 DO
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_asif_bmi (age)
        VALUES
        (intAge);
    END;
    END WHILE;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: *age 20 between 75* => `ROUND(20 + (75 - 20) * RAND())`. *WHILE counter <= 200 DO* - use single query with recursive CTE instead of SP.

Comment: You want 200 rows where every column matches the criteria?

Comment: Hi - please update your question to show example data of what you are trying to achieve and explain clearly what the issue is